# WRS2 package - robust 2-way ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, analysis, anova, robust

I am an R beginner and I'm trying to run a robust RM ANOVA using WRS2.

I've started with formatting the data with the IVs (Condition and GVS) as factors with 3 and 2 levels respectively (see below) but I'm not sure I'm formatting the ID column correctly (it's multiple rows per subject). The PD column in my data frame is the DV (numeric).

```
Participant<-factor(TerryRHWB$Participant, levels = c(1:36)) #is this the right way to classify subjects?
GVS<-factor(TerryRHWB$GVS, levels=c(1, 2, 3), labels=c("Sham", "LGVS", "RGVS")) #factorial variable with n levels
Condition<-factor(TerryRHWB$Condition, levels=c(1, 2), labels=c("RH", "WB"))
PD<-c(TerryRHWB$PD)
as.data.frame(TerryRHWB)`
```

After formatting the data (hopefully not too wrongly so), I load the library and type the fuction:

```
library(WRS2)
#2-way anova with interactions + post-hocs
t2way(formula=PD ~ Condition * GVS, data=TerryRHWB, tr = 0.2)
mcp2atm(formula=PD ~ Condition * GVS, data=TerryRHWB, tr = 0.2)`
```

What I get is this error:

```
t2way(formula=PD ~ Condition * GVS, data=TerryRHWB, tr = 0.2)
Error in x[[grp[i]]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index
mcp2atm(formula=PD ~ Condition * GVS, data=TerryRHWB, tr = 0.2)
Error in x[[j]] : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

It's probably something I've overlooked while formatting the data frame but I couldn't find a solution by surfing the web - any input on what the error means would be incredibly appreciated.

Here, the data I'm using:

```
   Participant Condition GVS   PD
1             1         1   1 -0.3
2             1         2   1  0.9
3             1         1   2  8.5
4             1         2   2 -1.7
5             1         1   3  0.4
6             1         2   3 -1.2
7             2         1   1  2.1
8             2         2   1 -1.1
9             2         1   2  0.8
10            2         2   2 -0.2
11            2         1   3  1.6
12            2         2   3  1.7
13            3         1   1 -0.3
14            3         2   1  0.9
15            3         1   2 -0.9
16            3         2   2  1.6
17            3         1   3 -2.6
18            3         2   3  0.2
19            4         1   1 -3.1
20            4         2   1  4.7
21            4         1   2 -1.7
22            4         2   2  1.8
23            4         1   3 -0.7
24            4         2   3 -0.5
25            5         1   1  2.2
26            5         2   1  3.4
27            5         1   2  3.0
28            5         2   2 -3.6
29            5         1   3  1.8
30            5         2   3 -5.9
31            6         1   1  0.0
32            6         2   1  2.8
33            6         1   2  4.0
34            6         2   2 -0.3
35            6         1   3 -0.1
36            6         2   3 -0.1
37            7         1   1 -0.9
38            7         2   1  0.1
39            7         1   2  0.0
40            7         2   2  0.4  
41            7         1   3 -0.9
42            7         2   3  0.1
43            8         1   1  1.1
44            8         2   1 -0.6
45            8         1   2 -0.2
46            8         2   2 -1.7  
47            8         1   3  1.7
48            8         2   3 -3.4
49            9         1   1  0.7
50            9         2   1  3.3
51            9         1   2 -3.6
52            9         2   2  3.0
53            9         1   3 -2.3
54            9         2   3 -0.3
55           10         1   1  3.0
56           10         2   1  0.2
57           10         1   2 -2.6
58           10         2   2  0.8
59           10         1   3 -1.0
60           10         2   3 -1.7
61           11         1   1  0.6
62           11         2   1  1.1 
63           11         1   2 -0.6
64           11         2   2  0.0
65           11         1   3  1.9
66           11         2   3 -0.8
67           12         1   1  1.3
68           12         2   1 -0.5
69           12         1   2 -0.4
70           12         2   2  0.9
71           12         1   3  1.3
72           12         2   3 -2.7
73           13         1   1  0.2
74           13         2   1  2.0
75           13         1   2 -2.1
76           13         2   2  1.8
77           13         1   3 -1.2
78           13         2   3  0.7
79           14         1   1 -0.4
80           14         2   1 -0.8
81           14         1   2 -0.3
82           14         2   2 -2.5
83           14         1   3  2.1
84           14         2   3  4.3
85           15         1   1 -1.1
86           15         2   1 -0.8
87           15         1   2 -1.1
88           15         2   2 -0.8
89           15         1   3  0.0
90           15         2   3 -2.2
91           16         1   1  1.7
92           16         2   1  1.1
93           16         1   2  1.4
94           16         2   2  0.0
95           16         1   3  1.2
96           16         2   3 -0.7
97           17         1   1  1.1
98           17         2   1  1.3
99           17         1   2 -0.1
100          17         2   2 -3.0
101          17         1   3  2.9
102          17         2   3  2.2
103          18         1   1 -1.0
104          18         2   1  0.4
105          18         1   2  1.0
106          18         2   2  0.6
107          18         1   3 -1.9
108          18         2   3  1.2
109          19         1   1  0.0
110          19         2   1 -0.8
111          19         1   2 -0.5
112          19         2   2  3.3 
113          19         1   3  0.7
114          19         2   3 -0.7
115          20         1   1 -0.5
116          20         2   1 -1.0
117          20         1   2  0.8
118          20         2   2 -0.3
119          20         1   3 -1.1
120          20         2   3  0.8
121          21         1   1 -0.2
122          21         2   1  0.0
123          21         1   2  1.5
124          21         2   2  9.4
125          21         1   3  2.1   
126          21         2   3  1.0
127          22         1   1  1.3
128          22         2   1 -0.1
129          22         1   2  1.3
130          22         2   2 -0.3
131          22         1   3 -1.4
132          22         2   3 -0.5
133          23         1   1 -0.8
134          23         2   1 -3.4
135          23         1   2 -1.0
136          23         2   2 -1.9
137          23         1   3  0.5
138          23         2   3  0.3
139          24         1   1  1.0
140          24         2   1  0.6
141          24         1   2  0.5
142          24         2   2  0.5
143          24         1   3 -0.9
144          24         2   3 -1.2
145          25         1   1 -2.6
146          25         2   1 -0.9
147          25         1   2 -3.1
148          25         2   2  3.3
149          25         1   3 -0.8
150          25         2   3  0.7
151          26         1   1 10.4
152          26         2   1  2.9
153          26         1   2  6.2
154          26         2   2  5.0
155          26         1   3  4.9
156          26         2   3  1.7
157          27         1   1  0.1
158          27         2   1 -0.2
159          27         1   2 -1.9
160          27         2   2  0.2
161          27         1   3  1.8
162          27         2   3  1.3
163          28         1   1 -0.5
164          28         2   1  0.3
165          28         1   2 -0.3
166          28         2   2 -2.4
167          28         1   3 -4.1
168          28         2   3 -0.6
169          29         1   1 -0.2
170          29         2   1  0.2
171          29         1   2 -0.1
172          29         2   2 -0.7
173          29         1   3  1.4
174          29         2   3  0.0
175          30         1   1 -2.1
176          30         2   1  0.2 
177          30         1   2  0.1
178          30         2   2  0.9
179          30         1   3  0.2
180          30         2   3  3.6
181          31         1   1 -2.3
182          31         2   1 -0.2
183          31         1   2 -1.0
184          31         2   2 -2.3
185          31         1   3  1.6
186          31         2   3  0.2
187          32         1   1  1.3 
188          32         2   1  2.9
189          32         1   2  0.2
190          32         2   2  2.0
191          32         1   3  0.1
192          32         2   3  0.4
193          33         1   1  2.3
194          33         2   1  3.3
195          33         1   2  1.1
196          33         2   2 -0.8
197          33         1   3  0.0
198          33         2   3  3.0
199          34         1   1 -0.2
200          34         2   1  0.0
201          34         1   2  1.0
202          34         2   2  2.4
203          34         1   3 -0.6
204          34         2   3  0.0
205          35         1   1 -0.8
206          35         2   1 -1.5
207          35         1   2 -0.9
208          35         2   2 -0.1
209          35         1   3  0.5
210          35         2   3 -0.7
211          36         1   1 -1.3
212          36         2   1  2.7
213          36         1   2 -0.3
214          36         2   2 -1.8
215          36         1   3 -1.7
216          36         2   3 -0.3
```

Thanks to anyone willing to take the time to help a newbie out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also a newbie but I have just had the same problem as you.
I found that by grouping the data and then making sure the IVs are factors, t2way works.

Try:

```
TerryRHWB <- TerryRHWB %>% group_by(Condition, GVS) # Group the data 
TerryRHWB$Condition <- factor(TerryRHWB$Condition) # convert to factor
TerryRHWB$GVS <- factor(TerryRHWB$GVS) # convert to factor
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jow, thanks a lot for your solution. It seemed to work the first couple of times but now it's acting out saying it doesn't recognise this: " %>% ". Did that happen to you too or do you happen to know anything about it? Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I think the %>% needs a package to be loaded for it to work. A google tells me its part of the dplyr package. So try: install.packages("dplyr") then library(dplyr) beforehand. You need to do the library part every time you open R